# Why do I get "TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable" when using numpy.hstack?

Tags: python, numpy

Can't understand how to fix the bug in this code.
This is an educational code, I am studying now ML technics.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.linalg as sla
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Lasso, Ridge


def f(x):
    """
        param x: np.array(np.float) vector of length 2
        return: np.float
    """
    return np.sum(np.sin(x)**2)

def grad_descent_2d(f, grad_f, lr, num_iter=100, x0=None):
    """
        a function that implements gradient descent to a minimum for a function f of two 
        variables.
        :param f: scalar function of two variables
        :param grad_f: a function that returns the gradient of the function f (arranged as 
        implemented by you above grad_f)
        :param lr: learning rate of the algorithm
        :param num_iter: number of iterations of gradient descent
        :return: np.array[num_iter, 2] pairs of the form (x, f(x))
    """
    if x0 is None:
        x0 = np.random.random(2)
```

we will save the values of the arguments and values of the function
in the process of hail. descent to the history variable

```
history = []

# # iteration of the cycle -- step of gradient descent
curr_x = x0.copy()
for iter_num in range(num_iter):
    np.hstack((curr_x, f(curr_x)))
    history.append(np.hstack((curr_x, f(curr_x))))

    curr_x = curr_x- lr*grad_f(curr_x) 

return np.vstack(history)

steps = grad_descent_2d(f, grad_f, lr=0.1, num_iter=20)
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-d21394828072> in <module>()
----> 1 steps = grad_descent_2d(f, grad_f, lr=0.1, num_iter=20)

<ipython-input-109-965895a484b9> in grad_descent_2d(f, grad_f, lr, num_iter, x0)
     18     curr_x = x0.copy()
     19     for iter_num in range(num_iter):
---> 20         np.hstack((curr_x, f(curr_x)))
     21         history.append(np.hstack((curr_x, f(curr_x))))
     22 

TypeError: 'Add' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is I should assign this expression to a variable:

```
entry = np.hstack((curr_x, f(curr_x)))
```